# Not able to call class member function in a separate thread using C++11 thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11, member-functions

I am having a hard time to get the right syntax for calling a class member function in separate thread . Neither of the three options are working . Line 1 and 2 are throwing compile time error while the third one is showing run time error . Can anybody tell me please what is the correct way .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
struct Complex 
{
    mutex mx;
    int i;
    Complex(int q) : i(q) {}
    void mul(int x) 
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
        int z = i*x;
        cout<<z<<endl;
    }
    void div(int x)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mx);
        int z = i/x;
        cout<<z<<endl;
    }
    void both(int x, int y) 
    {
         mul(x);
         div(y);
    }
};
int main()
{
    //Complex complex(9);
    //thread t(&Complex::both,&Complex(9),32, 23);     --1
    //thread t(&Complex::both,complex,32,23);          --2
    //thread t(&Complex::both,&complex,32,23);         --3
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

(1) doesn't work because the expression `&Complex(9)` is ill-formed - you are trying to take the address of a temporary and that is disallowed.

(2) doesn't work because `std::thread` will *copy* all of its arguments internally. `complex`'s copy constructor is defined as deleted because it contains a member of type `std::mutex` whose [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex) is deleted.

(3) compiles fine but will fail at runtime because the created thread `t` will be destroyed before it is joined. You will want to `join` it first:

```
std::thread t(&Complex::both, &complex, 32, 32);
t.join();
```

Comment: Well , thats perfect . Thank you for your answer !

Comment: The `std::ref` version depends on a [recently-fixed LWG issue](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2219) and may not work in some implementations.

Comment: @T.C. Just going to remove it. Didn't realize the `ref` stuff was so complicated... Thanks!